# Sed multiline replacement question

Tags: sed, multiline, replace

I am having a sed replacement issue and am hoping one of you will be able to help me. I am sure I am missing something simple.

So I have a file containing text and a quote. The quote itself could be on one line or span multiple lines. I want the quote on a new line by itself. As an example here is an example of the file

```
And he said "This too
   shall pass"
```

I need to change this to

```
And he said 
"This too shall pass"
```

I tried the following sed but it didn't work -- it seems to match alright but failed to get a new line

```
/"This/ {
    N
    s/"This *\n*too *\n*shall *\n*pass"/\n"This too shall pass"/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the "\n" with \ and an explicit new line; like the following --

```
/"This/ {
N
s/"This *\n*too *\n*shall *\n*pass"/\
"This too shall pass"/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First join all lines, then insert a newline for the first `"` and then a pass through `tr` to single space everything (not that happy with the `tr` part...)

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta ; s/"/\n"/' multiline_input | tr -s " "
And he said 
"This too shall pass"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -0777 -ne 's/\s+/ /g;s/"/\n"/;print "$_\n"'
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad! was aiming for the up-arrow but I missed and accidentally downvoted instead. I blame my dodgy mosepad.