# Sed unterminated `s' command multiline search and replace

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to update some SQL commands, but getting `unterminated`s' command`

Command:

```
sed -i -f commands.sed mySql.sql
```

commands.sed

```
s;      if @ARI is not NULL
        begin
                exec spRun @Name='Txn', @NextValue=@Txn output
;       if @ARI is not NULL
        begin
                select @Txn= @Txn+ 1
;g
```

Do you know why?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed multiline replacement question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350800/sed-multiline-replacement-question)

Comment: Im my opinion this is not a duplicate as it regards reading from a file which that question does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` works line-oriented. Your script contains newlines in patterns. So it complains about the first line,

```
s;      if @ARI is not NULL
```

which obviously is an unterminated substitution with `s`. You're probably better off using perl's regular expressions to deal with multiline substitutions in the spirit of

```
perl -0777 -ne 's/FROM\nLINE\n/TO\nTHIS\n/g;print'
```

Comment: > Your script contains newlines // thanks :-) This is very often issue in Python